# Is $\big\{x \in L^2[0,1]:\int_0^1x(t)\,dt=0\big\}$ a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have been stuck with this problem for two days, can I have hint to prove whether 
\begin{equation}
Y=\big\{
x \in L^2[0,1]:\int_0^1 x(t)\,dt=0
\big\}
\end{equation}
is a closed subset of $L^2[01,]$ or not?

Comment: Hint : the given set is the kernel of a bounded linear functional on $L^2([0,1])$. Which one? That is for you to see. Once you see this, the kernel of any bounded linear functional is closed since it is continuous, so the inverse image of a closed set is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES.

This is due to the fact that the functional $\varphi : L^2[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, with
$$
\varphi(\,f)=\int_0^1f\,dx
$$
is bounded (and hence continuous), since
$$
|\varphi(\,f)|\le\int_0^1|\,f|\,dx\le \left(\int_0^1|\,f|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2},
$$
and therefore $\varphi^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is a closed set.